# How to create a new char array in NASM assembly using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, assembly, nasm

Given this c code:

```
char** names=(char**)malloc(count*sizeof(char*));
```

I want to convert it to NASM assembly code. Here is what I tried, but the code crashes:

```
  mov eax, dword count
  mov ebx, [eax*4] ;; i did times 4 because we clear stack by 4 bits or bytes?
  push ebx
  call _malloc
  mov names, eax
  add esp, 4
```

What does `sizeof(char*)`mean? which char pointer is the code addressing?

Comment: `mov ebx, [eax*4]`  should be `lea ebx, [eax*4]` or just `shl eax, 2; push eax`.

Comment: It doesn't crash anymore. But what is the sizeof(char*). I have a feeling it is not 4.

Comment: @Jester you should post that as an answer!

Comment: `sizeof(char *)` is determining the size of a pointer on your system.  If you have a 64 bit system it is likely 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it crashes is because `mov ebx, [eax*4]` is accessing memory at address `eax * 4` which is unlikely to be valid, and definitely not what you want anyway. To multiply by 4, you can use `lea ebx, [eax*4]` or `shl eax, 2` then `push eax`.

PS: Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks. this really helped

Answer (score 1):

```
sizeof (char *)
```

returns the size of a pointer:

- 16 bits [2 bytes] for a `near` (small model) pointer
- 32 bits [4 bytes] for a `large` or `huge` model in real mode, or a pointer in 32-bit virtual mode
- 64 bits [8 bytes] for a pointer in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to know more about how it crashes. On which instruction?

To answer your question `sizeof(char *)` means the size of *any* `char *` -- they are all the same size.  32-bit pointers are 4 bytes long, 64-bit pointers are 8 bytes long.

The code isn't dereferencing any pointer inside `sizeof()`.  It's evaluated at compile-time and results in the size required to store a pointer of type `char *`.